# Rake - "bundle exec" -  how can I avoid `bundle exec` with my `rake spec`

Tags: ubuntu, rake

When I try to `bundle exec` I'm getting

`You have already activated rake 0.9.3.beta.1, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2.2. Using bundle exec may solve this.
...`

I have `rake`, version `0.9.3.beta.1`

I would like to have version `0.9.2.2`

How do I switch to it?

I'm on Ubuntu11

Comment: can clarify your ubuntu version ubuntu 11.04 or ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: The latest version I see on http://rake.rubyforge.org/, is 0.8.7. How did yo install 0.9.3.beta.1

Comment: @bbaja42 There are many ways to get the dev version - it can be installed from github, for example.

Comment: Hi Aboobacker Mk, it's Ubuntu11.10

Comment: Check out the Ruby Version Manager. https://rvm.io/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried installing the required version with `gem`?

```
$ gem install rake --version 0.9.2.2
```

Comment: This worked.  Furthermore I didn't need to 'remove' my 0.9.3.beta.1  I just installed 0.9.2.2 and it's now my new version.  Now I can `rake spec` without `bundle exec` !